# The operator $(Xf)(x)=-if'(x)$ has Fourier series as eigenfunctions. Which operator $ (Af)(x)=??$ has the Taylor series as its eigenfunctions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

The operator $$ (Xf)(x)=-if'(x)$$ has fourier series as its eigenfunctions. I was wondering what kind of operator $$ (Af)(x)=??$$ has the taylor series as its eigenfunctions?

Comment: $X$ is ususally the position operator, i.e. $(Xf)(x)=xf(x)$. Maybe you should change the notation.

Comment: Which notation would you suggest?

Comment: First of all, why do you consider the operator $X$ instead of the derivative $$(Df)(x)=f'(x)$$i.e. $Df=f'$?

Comment: Note that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A\colon V\to V$ if and only if it is an eigenvector of $\lambda A$ for $\lambda\neq 0$.